# Odoo 10 extra button in tree view firing the create function

Tags: python, odoo

Hey guys I created a button next to the create button in my tree/form view but it's not firing my desired function and instead it does the same as create.

**templatess.xml**

```
<template id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <!-- <t t-extend="FormView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="button.oe_form_button_create" t-operation="after">
        <button type="button">My button</button>
     </t>
    </t> -->
    <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
        <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="after">
            <t t-if="widget.model=='ba.data'">
                <button name="fetch" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm o_list_button_add" type="button">Fetch Data</button>
            </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

**ba_data.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api, exceptions

class Session(models.Model):
    _name = 'ba.data'

    name = fields.Char(required=True)

    @api.one
    def fetch(self):
    # SOME CODE HERE
```

Also, if possible please let me know how to add the button next to import instead of create. Thank you very much in advantage.

Refer to the working view:
[Working view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iZQL.png)

Comment: You need to write a listener in JS to catch your button. See more here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42764924/6050822](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42764924/6050822)

Comment: `o_list_button_add` is the name of the Create button. You need to replace it with the name of the Import button. Than it should work

Comment: Can explain what is your goal to add button next to create ?

Comment: I want to make some http calls, parse the JSON data and create new entries in the view.
I'll try @qvpham approach. Thank you guys.